# Why does `np.median` behave differently from some other `numpy` functions in a `pandas` `groupby/apply`?

Tags: pandas, numpy

Why are the return values from `np.median` different from a few other common summary statistical functions in a `pandas` `groupby/apply`?

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': np.random.choice(['a', 'b'], 10), 'value': np.random.randint(1, 10, 10)})

df.groupby('group')[['value']].apply(np.min)  # Returns a DataFrame
df.groupby('group')[['value']].apply(np.mean)  # Returns a DataFrame
df.groupby('group')[['value']].apply(np.std)  # Returns a DataFrame
df.groupby('group')[['value']].apply(np.median)  # Returns a Series
```

gives

```
    value
group   
a   6
b   2

    value
group   
a   7.00
b   6.25

    value
group   
a   1.00
b   2.49

group
a   7.00
b   7.00
dtype: float64
```

And if I replace `[['value']]` with `['value']` then they are all the same.

This has been tested on `numpy` 1.19.x and 1.20.x and `pandas` 1.2.x.

Comment: Just curious, why `groupby().apply(np.median)` but not `groupby().median()`?

Comment: you could just use `groupby.describe()` instead of calling 4 functions.

Comment: Since you're reducing the input to a single result, `df.groupby('group')[['value']].agg(np.median)` works as expected.